# Using a message send to set `UILabel` text

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uilabel, message

I've read on here how it is quite easy to set the text of a `UILabel` through code. The only issue that I'm having right now is correct syntax. I have a message send, `[myReciever readValue];` that is used to check a value in a specific location. I'm trying to set the `UILabel`'s text to match the return value of that message send. Here is what I've tried:

```
self.myLabel.text = @"%@",[myReciever readValue];
```

^ This only sets the label as `%@`.

```
  NSString *stringText = [myReciever readValue]; 
        self.myLabel.text = (@"%@", stringText);
```

^ This makes the text disappear completely. Does anyone know how I can use a message send to set the text of a `UILabel`? Also, the message send **returns a string**.

Comment: `self.myLabel.text = [myReciever readValue];`

Comment: Huh. Familiarize yourself with basic Objective-C syntax first. Format strings are not omnipotent, and the compiler is neither AI nor magic. Why did you *assume* at all that any of this would work?

Comment: @H2CO3 A million dollars to the person that creates the "do what I meant, not what I said" compiler.

Comment: @rmaddy That compiler would do some seriously bad things to certain Stack Overflow-askers if I was using it... :P

Comment: @Wain Thanks, I tried that but it is returning just a blank field.

Comment: Also, the message send returns a string.

Comment: @OralB Use the debugger and see what your `readValue` method is returning. It may be returning `nil` or the empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
self.myLabel.text = [myReceiver readValue];
```

Perhaps you were trying to format the string:

```
self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [myReceiver readValue]];
```

Of course this is pointless since you already have a string. Using `stringWithFormat:` like this is the most overused construct seen on the iOS section of stackoverflow.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure, I just +1'd it. I used the debugger, and the value returns as normal. I used `NSLog(@"%@", [myReciever readValue]);` It logs a number like 4.32. I tried your both your lines above, but they both just returned a blank field. I also tried just self.myLabel.text = 6 to make sure it works, and it worked fine. Maybe it's because [myReceiver readValue]; returns a string?

Comment: There is no way you did `self.myLabel.text = 6;`. Perhaps you meant `self.myLabel.text = @"6";`. Please be precise. It is important. If calling `[myReceiver readValue]` really returns an `NSString` with a value of `@"4.32"` and `directly setting `self.myLabel.text` to a literal works, then it makes no sense that assigning `[myReceiver readValue]` to `self.myLabel.text` would result in an empty label.